# How can I share a folder on MacOS, and not allow an attacker to brute force my accounts?

Tags: network, wifi, security, file-sharing, family-sharing

I want to share a folder between my MacBook Pros while connected to home wifi, and not risk security while traveling with the laptop.

I'm particularly concerned about a brute force attack that can be used to deduce the administrator password.

My solution is to create a "share only" user account that only has access to this folder.  Is this a sufficient mitigation, or should I do more to prevent network attacks?

Comment: At the end of the day, you can't completely prevent an attack.  You can secure different attack vectors though.  Could you add more detail?  For example, you could add a $15k UTM with endpoint protection, use MAC address filtering on the network, hide the SSID, use enterprise-level devices with RADIUS to even get on the network, and then tune your Mac to be as secure as possible, and only turn the share on when you need it, and turn it off right afterwards.  But even that wouldn't guarantee your security 100%.  So what exactly are you trying to protect against, and through which vector(s)?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the side effects (new vulnerabilities) that open up once I enable file sharing.  Day to day use (accessing Starbucks Wifi, etc) is unchanged from a typical user. @harv